# How to execute two different query with single foreach in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I am working with Php and right now i am inserting query using foreach loop (passing array) but how can i use another query with foreach and pass value into same array ?
Here is my current code

```
$data=$this->db->get($firstquery) // first query record in array
$second=$this->db->get($second_query);  // second query record in array
foreach($records as $rec)
{
   $data22 = array
        (
                'file_id'=>$rec['id'],  // here is first query result
                'text'=>    // How to pass second query result here 
        );
}
```

Comment: Do they share a foreign key so you can link them together in one query? Seems like an N+1 issue. You can attempt to trust `array_merge` but we'd need to see the data.

Comment: @Jaquarh data will be equal ( for both queries) kindly give me hint how can i do this ?

Comment: I cannot hint you when I don't have a clue what the data consists of, if its in the exact same order then you could always just use a `for` loop and access each array with its index but this still feels like you should be joining on a foriegn key so you don't have this problem

Comment: if there is a relationship (foreign key) between the two queries (tables) you use a join, if *data will be equal* (if that means the same table) your query is wrong, it should return both file_id and text in one query only, no need of the second. Anyway you need to show us your data structure to be able to give an answer. Please see: 
[Why should I provide a MRE - Minimal Reproducible Example - 
for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1):

You can call another loop inside main loop and execute another query

```
$data=$this->db->get($firstquery) // first query record in array
$second=$this->db->get($second_query);  // second query record in array
foreach($records as $rec)
{   
         foreach($second as $sec)   //second query loop
         {
          //enter code here
         }
   $data22 = array
        (
                'file_id'=>$rec['id'],  // here is first query result
                'text'=>    // How to pass second query result here 
        );
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what difference this has to the OP?